How to mock a Micronaut network call with generics?
I have code that loads a public key via Micronaut HTTP:
import io.micronaut.http.HttpRequest
import io.micronaut.http.client.HttpClient

class Mcve(val client: HttpClient) {
    fun loadKey(): String {
        val keyRequest = HttpRequest.GET<String>("https://example.org/key")
        val keyResponse = client.toBlocking().exchange(keyRequest, String::class.java)
        return keyResponse.body()
    }
}

In testing with mockk, I don't want the network request to go out, but instead I want to return a dummy key. I don't want to mock the class under test, I'd rather mock the HttpClient calls.
(I'd like to keep Micronaut's DI framework and its slow startup out of this test, hence no @MicronautTest.)
import io.micronaut.http.HttpRequest
import io.micronaut.http.client.BlockingHttpClient
import io.micronaut.http.client.HttpClient
import io.mockk.coEvery
import io.mockk.mockk
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import kotlin.test.assertEquals

class McveTest {
    @Test
    fun usesDummyKey() {
        val keyClient: HttpClient = mockk(relaxed = true)
        val blockMock: BlockingHttpClient = mockk(relaxed = true)

        coEvery {
            keyService.toBlocking()
        } returns blockMock
        coEvery {
//            blockMock.exchange(HttpRequest::class, String::class)
//            blockMock.exchange(HttpRequest<String>, String::class)
//            blockMock.exchange(ofType<HttpRequest<any()>>, String::class)
            blockMock.exchange(HttpRequest.GET(any()), String::class)
        } returns "dummy key"

        assertEquals("dummy key", Mcve(keyClient).loadKey())
    }
}

IntelliJ complains about my blockMock.exchange:
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
exchange(HttpRequest<TypeVariable(I)!>!, Argument<TypeVariable(O)!>!)
   where I = TypeVariable(I), O = TypeVariable(O) for
   fun <I : Any!, O : Any!> exchange(request: HttpRequest<I!>!, bodyType: Argument<O!>!): HttpResponse<O!>! defined in io.micronaut.http.client.BlockingHttpClient
exchange(HttpRequest<TypeVariable(I)!>!, Class<TypeVariable(O)!>!)
   where I = TypeVariable(I), O = TypeVariable(O) for
   fun <I : Any!, O : Any!> exchange(request: HttpRequest<I!>!, bodyType: Class<O!>!): HttpResponse<O!>! defined in io.micronaut.http.client.BlockingHttpClient
exchange(String!, Class<TypeVariable(O)!>!)
   where O = TypeVariable(O) for
   fun <O : Any!> exchange(uri: String!, bodyType: Class<O!>!): HttpResponse<O!>! defined in io.micronaut.http.client.BlockingHttpClient

I've seen Mockk match overloaded function with generics but the suggested ideas still got the compiler error above.
How do I mock the exchange call or somehow else pass a dummy key to loadKey?

I believe replacing your low-level client with a declarative client will take you further: https://docs.micronaut.io/4.4.3/guide/#clientAnnotation BR

@RoarS. Thanks! I try to avoid pulling the DI mechanisms into my unit tests as this slows them down so much. I do however have a client via application.yaml for prod. Anyway, I avoided the problem by using retrieve instead of exchange and that doesn't have these mocking problems.
